# Trying to set the scroll state of a RecyclerView when it is recreated, but Kotlin says I can't because the setter is public...?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Like the title says, I am trying to set the scroll state of a recycler view in the onViewCreated method of the Fragment. I call

```
recycler.scrollState = MainViewModel.sharedViewModel.savedScrollState
```

and I get this error:

```
the setter is public/*package*/ for synthetic extension in '<dependencies of app_debug>'
```

Why can't I use a public setter?

Comment: `RecyclerView` doesn't expose method for you to set scrollstate. scrollstate has only package level access. It is public for read purposes. What is your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RecyclerView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.java) source code

```
void setScrollState(int state) {
    if (state == mScrollState) {
        return;
    }
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setting scroll state to " + state + " from " + mScrollState,
                new Exception());
    }
    mScrollState = state;
    if (state != SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
        stopScrollersInternal();
    }
    dispatchOnScrollStateChanged(state);
}
```

As you can see, the access modifier of this method is default (or package), it means only classes in the same package can call this method.

Because you call this method from your code which has the different package, that why the compiler show that error.

**Solution:** You can invoke this method at runtime using [Java Reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html)

1.Define a method to set scroll state for a recyclerview

```
private fun setScrollState(recyclerView: RecyclerView, state: Int) {
    val method = recyclerView::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("setScrollState", Int::class.java)
    method.isAccessible = true
    method.invoke(recyclerView, state)
}
```

2.Call this method whenever you want to set scroll state for a recyclerview.

```
// recycler.scrollState = MainViewModel.sharedViewModel.savedScrollState
setScrollState(recycler, MainViewModel.sharedViewModel.savedScrollState)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. unfortunately Scroll state is not the scroll position like I thought.

Comment: @Xials Because you do not describe your problem so I cannot help. In case you want to scroll to a position in a recyclerview, try to collaborate with `scrollToPosition(int position)` method.